# Увеличение вложенности массива с каждой итерацией JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, рекурсия

Стоит задача создать массив, с каждой итерацией его вложенность должна увеличиваться:

Массив такого вида:

- **ar[0]** содержит **3** числа;
- **ar[1]** содержит **3** массива, в каждом **3** числа;
- **ar[2]** содержит **3** массива, в каждом **3** массива, в каждом **3** числа;
- **ar[3]** содержит **3** массива, в каждом **3** массива, в каждом **3** массива, в каждом **3** числа;
  и т.д.

В общем вид на подобии этого:

```
var ar = [
    [1,2,3],
    [
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
        [10,11,12]
    ],
    [
        [
            [13,14,15],
            [16,17,18],
            [19,20,21]
        ],
        [
            [22,23,24],
            [25,26,27],
            [28,29,30]
        ],
        [
            [31,32,33],
            [34,35,36],
            [37,38,39],
        ],
        [
            [40,41,42],
            [43,44,45],
            [46,47,48],
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

Пытался реализовать это через рекурсивную функцию, но не выходит, что можете посоветовать? Буду рад любой подсказке!

Comment: На слова "я пытался, но не выходит" ответ всегда один - пытайся дальше.

Comment: @Эникейщик, однако через рекурсивную функцию, верный подход? Ранее не приходилось с подобным сталкиваться.

Comment: Приложите функцию, вам подскажут где ошибка. А так с нуля тут редко помогают.

Comment: ух, массив то хоть конечный?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, да, забыл упомянуть, что на ввод идёт уровень вложенности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А я подумал в эту сторону:

```
[0,0,0], // ← a

[
  [0,0,0], // ← a
  [0,0,0], // ← a
  [0,0,0], // ← a
], // ← b

[
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // ← b
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // ← b
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // ← b
]
```

Т.е. каждый следующий элемент массива должен содержать три элемента, похожих на предыдущий элемент, которые отличаются только наполнением-числами. Можно пока решать вопрос со вложенностью, а с заполнением разберемся потом?)

В итоге, решилось так:

```js
let nesting_level = 5; // Уровень вложенности;

let arr = [], n = 1, last = "0";

for (let i = 0; i < nesting_level; i++ ) {
  let curr = `[${last},${last},${last}]`.replace(/\d+/g, _ => n++);
  arr.push( JSON.parse(curr) );
  last = curr;
}

console.log(arr);
```

На каждом круге создается строка, похожая на массив, содержащая три одинаковых, предыдущих элемента. Оттуда все совпадения с числами заменяются на нужное число. Ура!)

P.s. При желании, создание каждого нового массива, и его заполнение числами - можно заменить на отдельную рекурсию.

Comment: Отличное вышло решение)

Comment: Ого, интересный способ!

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME полезный интересный ответ для меня

Comment: Очень оригинальное решение, но в реальном надо учитывать, что регулярки и парсинг -- относительно дорогие операции.

Answer (score 3):

Можно реализовать таким образом. Сделал с помощью вспомогательной рекурсивной функции, которая сначала чанкует массив по три значения. Промежуточный результат будет следующим:

```
// [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] и так далее
```

Следующая же функция чанкует элементы промежуточного массива, кроме первого элемента. Функция так же является рекурсивной.

```js
const arr = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48
];

const makeChunks = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  const chunk = arr.slice(0, 3);
  const restArray = arr.slice(3);

  return [chunk, ...makeChunks(restArray)];
};

const intermediateResult = makeChunks(arr);

const increaseArrayNesting = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  const [head, ...tail] = arr;
  const chunkedRestArray = makeChunks(tail);

  return [head, ...increaseArrayNesting(chunkedRestArray)];
};

console.log(increaseArrayNesting(intermediateResult));
```

Уверен, что можно сделать одну функцию для решения задачи или же решить изящнее. По крайней мере задам направление. Надеюсь, в скобках не запутался при проверке)